# Custom Ruby/rails model validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have created a custom validation for a ruby model (using the luhn algorithm). Even when I explicitly just return `false` from the custom validation, the object still saves.

This is what I have in my CreditCard model:

```
before_save :check_card_number

  private
  def check_card_number
    return false unless card_number_luhn
  end

  def card_number_luhn
     #luhn_algorithm_here_that_returns_true_or_false
  end
```

but even if I just return false:

```
before_save :check_card_number

  private
  def check_card_number
    return false
  end

#so this is never even called
  def card_number_luhn
     #luhn_algorithm_here_that_returns_true_or_false
  end
```

the object still saves. This is true EVEN IF I use `validate` instead of `before_save`. What is going on?

Comment: what's rails version ?

Comment: Rails version 6.1.4, using Sqlite3

Comment: This isn't a "model validation", but it really should be. Use `validate`, not `before_save`.

Comment: I tried that too! Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Rails 5, you need to explicitly call `throw(:abort)`

```rb
# ...
before_save :check_card_number
# ...
def card_number_luhn
 valid = #luhn_algorithm_here_that_returns_true_or_false
 throw(:abort) unless valid
end
```

another way:

`ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = true`

reference: https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-does-not-halt-callback-chain-when-false-is-returned